# Closing or mark questions as answered

Tags: support, closed-questions, exact-duplicates

I noted that the question: [Remote access through carrier-grade NAT](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/remote-access-through-carrier-grade-nat)

is answered, but not via a answer but via a reference to another answer.

The thing is that it is still marked as "0" answers and status as unanswered.

Is there a way of changing the status to "Answered"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the reasoning is that it is actually answered by the question which is referenced — or more precisely that question's answer. Thus, it doesn't require an answer on the same page.

That is why one should not mark a question as duplicate of another question that does not have an answer. The goal is always to provide the asking person with an answer.

If you're asking due to search reasons, you can filter out duplicates by using "closed:0" in searches.

Comment: The system actually prevents you from closing as duplicate of an unanswered question too (but you can close as duplicate of an unanswered question *if* the dupe was asked by the same user, e.g. if a user asks an identical question twice and the first hasn't been answered yet)

Comment: @Helmar, 7 seconds... I like your precise answer any way +++

Answer (score 5):

That question is **closed** as a duplicate of a different question. There isn't any need to "mark it as answered" in any way, for a couple of reasons:

- Users who aren't logged in (and, for example, find that question through search results) **will automatically be redirected** to the [duplicate target](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/contacting-arduino-through-internet-without-port-forward). Open an Incognito tab and click the link in your meta question to try it; you won't see the unanswered question!
- Closed questions don't show up [in the unanswered tab](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-access?sort=unanswered&pageSize=15) (note that the link there is for the unanswered tab of [remote-access](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-access)), which the question is tagged with. It also won't count as unanswered in our [site stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94224/internet-of-things).

In our system, a question is considered 'answered' in the unanswered questions tab if it has **at least one answer with score > 0 or accepted**. So essentially, in direct answer to your question, **no, there's no way to manually mark it as solved, but there's no need to do that anyway!**

<sup>By the way: welcome to the site!</sup>

Comment: hahaha 7 seconds earlier :)

Comment: Thx for the welcome and the fast reply, much more welcoming than other SE groups. And the question is from the perspective that in "Top Q.." q's are NOT greenish and "Answer is zero" and from a user perspective it's a bit misleading. But that's me..

Comment: @MatsK Yeah, it's a little bit confusing at first. I guess the logic is that the question itself doesn't have any answers, but the duplicate has answers (which is why `[duplicate]` is appended to the title). Hopefully it should feel natural as you use Stack Exchange more; things can be a little complicated but there's usually a reason. Hope to see you around the site in the future!